# localStorage (Need help doesn't function properly) - Javascript Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

```
var itemName;
var itemSize;
var itemType;
var itemColor;

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('item_save').onclick = function() {

        var item_name = document.getElementById('item_name').value;
        var item_size = document.getElementById('item_size').value;
        var item_type = document.getElementById('item_type').value;
        var item_color = document.getElementById('item_color').value;

        console.log(item_name + "\t" + item_size + "\t" + item_type + "\t" + item_color + "\tsaving...");

        localStorage.setItem(itemName, item_name);
        localStorage.setItem(itemSize, item_size);
        localStorage.setItem(itemType, item_type);
        localStorage.setItem(itemColor, item_color);


    }

    var getItemName = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
    var getItemSize = localStorage.getItem(itemSize);
    var getItemType = localStorage.getItem(itemType);
    var getItemColor = localStorage.getItem(itemColor);

    console.log(getItemName + "\t" + getItemSize + "\t" + getItemType + "\t" + getItemColor + "\tsaved...")
}
```

Say if I enter 1 for the item_name input, 2 for the item_size input, 3 for the item_type input and 4 for the item_color input, it keeps displaying in console as:

"4    4    4    4    saved...

1    2    3    4    saving..."

I was wondering why it displays the saved console.log first as well and making all the numbers 4 in the saved console.log, need advice.

Comment: The first argument to `.setItem()` should be a string. You're passing uninitialized variables, so that'll be taken as the item name `"undefined"`.

Comment: how should i change it?

Comment: The variables like `itemName` etc are not really necessary, but you could initialize them with string values (`var itemName = "itemName";` etc). Or you could use the strings directly.

Comment: Thanks :) How do I make it so the saved console.log displays after?
(Never mind, im dumb lol)

Answer (score 2):

The "saving" console appears on event "click".

The "saved" console appears on event "load".

Of course, the loading is done before any other event is fired, liked "click".

And just like said @Pointy, the first parameter of "saveItem" and "getItem" should be a string.

By this way, you saved everything under "undefined" key and got everything under "undefined" key. Then, you only got the last saved value 4 and fourth times.